# Issues with loading consecutive files on 3js

Tags: javascript, 3d, web3js, .obj

I am trying to create a 3d model viewing website for various student projects. Currently pulling from the 3js library to reference OBJs and MTLs on server. The idea is that you can click on the left box of each student wrap div to open a modal with a 3js file viewer.

This works 100% of the time the first time you view a model (first execution of render function), but opening and closing models will often result in MTLs being dropped, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJvKT.png). Testing on multiple devices it seems that devices with faster internet connection/more processing power can actually load more files before corruption begins. In addition, not rotating the viewer seems to allow more files to be opened.

No error messages for the JS can be found in the Inspector. Messages sent from the 3js library files, however, show numerous errors any time a second/third/nth file is loaded without JS refresh. Putting in `location.window.reload()` in the exit function refreshes JS each time and fixes the error, but that causes a whole other set of problems.

The site with all source code and files can be accessed here: [biszweb](https://biszweb.club/gallery/3Al.html).

I will be able to provide more information is needed.

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Certain parts of 3.js need to be reloaded after rendering a model. Simple fix would be to insert a js reloading script.